# I am getting $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ even if the correlation coefficient $\rho≠0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation

Given a uniformly distributed PDF
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4ah}
$$
With the support$$S=\{(x,y):
-a+bx<y<a+bx,\ \ -h<x<h\}
$$
for some constants $a,b,h$

[image: Region]

---

Then for $-h<x<h$
$$
f_X(x)=\int^{a+bx}_{-a+bx}\frac{1}{4ah}dy=\frac{1}{2h}
$$
and
$$
f_Y(y)=\int^{h}_{-h}\frac{1}{4ah}dx=\frac{1}{2a}
$$

So $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ implying independence

---

Now, the solution on the book also attempted to find the correlation coefficient $\rho$

Since the conditional expectation is linear in $X$: $$E(Y|X=x)=bx$$ $$
\text{Var}(Y|X=x)=\frac{a^2}{3}
$$

We use the theorem for linear conditional expectation:

> $$
> E(Y|X=x)=\mu_Y + \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)
> $$
> and
> $$
> E(\text{Var}(Y|X=x))=\sigma^2_Y(1-\rho^2)
> $$
> where $\mu, \sigma$ denote the mean and variance respectively

From the theorem, $
b=\rho\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}
$ and $\frac{a^2}{3}(\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2))$
Which gives
$$
\rho=\frac{bh}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2h^2}}
$$

---

$\rho$ is not necessarily $0$ so we can choose the parameters $b,h$ such that $\rho≠0$ implying dependence between $X,Y$.

Comment: Hint: can you write down the densities with an indicator function for the supports of $X, Y, (X,Y)$? In particular, is the cartesian product of the supports of $X$ and $Y$ the support of $(X,Y)$?

Comment: @JoseAvilez I'm sorry, I misplaced $f_X$ with $f_Y$. I have the support of $f_X$ included in the edit however I have trouble in finding the support of $f_Y$ since it is dependent on $x$. There is no other given aside from the density with the support $S$ and the fact that it is uniformly distributed in a parallelogram like region in $X,Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay closer attention to the support.

Since for any given $x$, the values of $y$ are bounded by functions of $x$, therefore you should anticipate dependence.

---

Firstly, the domain of $S=\{(x,y): -a+bx<y<a+bx\,, -h<x<h\}$ means that

$$\begin{align}f_X(x) &=\int_{-a+bx}^{a+bx}\dfrac{\mathbf 1_{-h<x<h}}{4ha}\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{1}{2h}~\mathbf 1_{-h<x<h}\end{align}$$

[Note: because we want the marginal of $x$ we 'integrate out' $y$ over where it is supported relative to $x$.]

Nextly, by rewriting the domain $S=\{(x,y):  (y-a)/b<x<(y+a)/b\,, -a-bh<y<a+bh\}$, we likewise have:

$$\begin{align}f_{Y}(y) &=\int_{(y-a)/b}^{(y+a)/b}\dfrac{\mathbf 1_{-(a+bh)<y<(a+bh)}}{4ha}\,\mathrm d x\\&=\dfrac{1}{2bh}\mathbf 1_{-(a+bh)<y<(a+bh)}\end{align}$$

So $f_X(x)f_Y(y) = \dfrac{1}{4bh^2}\mathbf 1_{-h<x<h, -(a+bh)<y<(a+bh)}$ which does not equal to the joint p.d. function.